# How to implement ReaderPageViewer in Windows Phone 8 C#

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

### How to implement ReaderPageViewer in Windows Phone 8 C#......

Hi,
We are working on windows phone8 reader application.We are stuck in our reader page.Because we have a magazine with 60 pages,each page should fit on the screen in a panorama control.And it should support pinch zoom on each item.

We can fit the panorama page in a full screen,when we use panoramaitem template with orientation horizontal.Otherwise it does not support full screen and we need to block last to first navigation.

Is it possible to do any other pageviewer mechanism in windowsphone 8 other than pivot and panorama control?

Comment: WHat have you done so far? Show some code, please...

Comment: I have searched a lot and tried to load pages in listbox as mentioned in the below link.But could not implement it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374732/how-to-have-photo-viewer-style-pages. Please give me a clear idea about it..